# QML state not changing on C++ signal

Tags: qt, signals, qml, qtquick2

I'm struggling to understand the QML state concept.

I have the following code:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

Rectangle{
    id: myRectangle
    width: 500
    height: 120

    state: "init"

    Button {

        id: myBtn1
        text: "hello"
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 40
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        onClicked: {
            console.log("trying to change state to myState "
            myRectangle.state = "customState"
        }
    }
    Button {
        id: myBtn2
        text: "bye"
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 40
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        onClicked: {
            myCppObject.coolFunction()
        }
        visible: false
    }

    Connections {
        target: myCppObject
        onCoolSignal: {
            console.log("signal triggered")
            console.log("state before signal: " + myRectangle.state);

            myRectangle.state = "init";

            console.log("state after signal: " + myRectangle.state);
        }

    }

    states: [
            State {
                name: "init"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: myBtn1
                    visible:true
                }
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: myBtn2
                    visible: false
                }
            },
            State {
                name: "customState"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: myBtn1
                    visible: false
                }
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: myBtn2
                    visible: true
                }
            }
    ]
}
```

My intension is that on click on the "myBtn1" this button should disappear and "myBtn2" should show up. Therefore I use the states as described and it so far it work! The state changes and the button with the label "bye" is visible.

In the next step the click on the button "myBtn2" calls the function "coolFunction" of "myCppObject" which only purpose is to emit a signal called "coolSignal" - which also works!
 My problem is that I do get the expected output in the console which is like:

```
signal triggered
state before signal: customState
state after signal: init
```

but "myBtn1" stays hidden and "myBtn2" stays visible!!! So the state is not really changed!!!
Any ideas what I'm not understanding about states in QML?

btw: if I change `myBtn2.onClick` to `myRectangle.state = "init";` the state transition works!!! But I really need it to happen on a custom C++ signal!

Thanks for any kind of help in advance.

EDIT:
I forgot to say that I don't use the source code written on the top inside the main.qml. It's inside an extra QML File called MyElem.qml which used as delegate elem for a listview. This means while running there is more than one of MyElem loaded and all of them have the same id (myRectangle). Is this the reason why I don't see any visual changes?

Comment: I just figured out that not only the signal changes within the Connection take no visible effect, but also all other visible effect like `myBtn.visible = false`. So do I need to rerender the Rectangle somehow???

Comment: i have the same problem now. Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and in my case I solved it by adding a property bool isCustomState (you could use an int if you need more that 2 states) and giving the states a when condition. Then make any chages via the property.

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

Rectangle{
    id: myRectangle
    width: 500
    height: 120

    property bool isCustomState: false

    Button {

        id: myBtn1
        text: "hello"
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 40
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        onClicked: {
            console.log("trying to change state to myState");
            myRectangle.isCustomState = true;
        }
    }
    Button {
        id: myBtn2
        text: "bye"
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 40
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        onClicked: {
            myCppObject.coolFunction()
        }
        visible: false
    }

    Connections {
        target: myCppObject
        onCoolSignal: {
            console.log("signal triggered")
            console.log("state before signal: " + myRectangle.state);

            myRectangle.isCustomState = false;

            console.log("state after signal: " + myRectangle.state);
        }

    }

    states: [
            State {
                name: "init"
                when: !isCustomState
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: myBtn1
                    visible:true
                }
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: myBtn2
                    visible: false
                }
            },
            State {
                name: "customState"
                when: isCustomState
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: myBtn1
                    visible: false
                }
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: myBtn2
                    visible: true
                }
            }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick handler in Button 1 is referencing myGame instead of myRectangle.  Since the signal in your Connections only resets the state to init you are not seeing anything happen because you are never successfully changing the state of myRectangle to anything other than init.  There should have been an error message in your output about referencing a non existant object....

Comment: thx, for your responce. sorry but myGame is a typo that only exists in this example. I reduced my real code to this in order to focus on the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

The example code works as expected after fixing typos so that it builds using Qt 5.15. For the purposes of testing, I created an object that emits `coolSignal()` each time `coolFunction()` is called.

These are the possible causes for the problem:

1. Code in example addressed the defect and the poster failed to test it.

   - Clearly, the poster did not test the example code because it does not run:

     `console.log("trying to change state to myState "` is missing the closing parenthesis.
   - I think the poster made a good-faith effort to describe the problem but made mistakes while reducing the code for the post. They could have addressed the defect and not understood that the reduced code did not reproduce the issue.
2. Defect in Qt framework.

   - Qt version is not given in post, but the `QtQuick 2.1` declaration implies Qt 5.1 which was very buggy. I tested with Qt 5.15.11 which is very stable.
3. C++ object, `myCppObject`, does not emit signal consistently.

   - The C++ object **must** emit `coolSignal()` signal when `coolFunction()` is called or code will fail as described.
4. Did not run `qmake` after adding signal to C++ declaration.

   - Must run `qmake` after adding the a new signal declaration, `coolSignal()`, to force the meta-object compiler (MOC) to generate the code necessary for the QML `Connections` element to bind to the `onCoolSignal` handler.

     Modern Qt Creator may run `qmake` automatically, but cerca-2013 Qt Creator 3 required either cleaning the project, a full rebuild, or manually running `qmake` to invoke the MOC.
5. A `states` declaration collision in QML component derived from this one.

   - The `states` property declaration is at the root scope of this component. If another QML component is derived from this one and also declares a `states` property at the root level, that declaration replaces this component's `states` declaration.

     If the `State` `name` properties in the derived component do not match "init" or "customState", the inital button press behavior would be flat-out broken. But if the coder uses consistent implementation patterns and reuses the same names and even element ids, the derived component's states will modify the base component in unexpected ways.
6. Broken binding.

   - The code assigns directly to the  `state` property instead of using the `when` property in both `State` elements. This is error-prone.

     The example given by "Sumyrda - remember Monica" is good usage of the `when` property.